# Passing Two items in a ViewModel's constructor in Catel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

Can a UserControl's ViewModel constructor be set up to fire with the view's DataContext AND another dependency injection?

I would like to be able to get the UserControl's datacontext (set in it's parent's veiw) and a database service into a ViewModel.

Can't figure this out:

```
public MyUserControlViewModel( theDataContext, InvoiceService)
{

}
```

This works:

```
public MyUserControlViewModel( theDataContext)
{

}
```

This works:

```
 public MyUserControlViewModel( InvoiceService)
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Catel supports of all this. In the case that you have above, all should work. For example:

public MyViewModel(Model model, IService1 service1, IService2 service2)
{
}

Note that in order to inject a model, it must be set as data context. All services except for the model must be registered in the ServiceLocator.

Comment: I can inject multiple services (iservice1 service1, iservice2 service2), or a Model in the view's DataContext (Model model), but it breaks when I mix them: (Model model, IService1 service1, IService2 service2). I'll try to isolate things to see if that is really what's going on, or if something else is breaking things.

Comment: I built a test app and the injection indeed breaks when combining the DataContext and a service, but works separately.

Comment: I have 3.5 on one computer and I'm pretty sure 3.9 on another.

Comment: The error did not reproduce itself in small test app in Catel 3.9 Version.

Comment: Yes, upgrade fixed other machines.